# How can i store values from one array to another array?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have two text files, which contain Bangla language plain text. I read the two files and store each file's text line by line in two arrays. Now I am trying to store one array value into another array but I found an error. Code is bellow with the error message.

```
f = open("doc1.txt", encoding = 'utf-8')
a1 = f.read()
f = open("doc2.txt", encoding = 'utf-8')
a2 = f.read()
sentence1 = a1.split("।")
sentence2 = a2.split("।")

np_sent1 = np.array(sentence1)
np_sent2 = np.array(sentence2)

len_np_sent1 = len(np_sent1)
len_np_sent2 = len(np_sent2)

rint(np_sent1.shape)

for x in range(len_np_sent2):
    len_np_sent1 = len_np_sent1 + 1;
    np_sent1[len_np_sent1] = np_sent2[x]
print(np_sent1,len(np_sent1))
```

**Error message:**

```
IndexError: index 11 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 10

 15     np_sent1[len_np_sent1] = np_sent2[x]
```

Comment: The error is clear. `np_sent1` contains 10 elements yet you are trying to access the 11th element, which does not exist

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `np.append` or `np.concatenate`.

`np.append` uses `np.concatenate` internally.

**Change**

```py
for x in range(len_np_sent2):
    len_np_sent1 = len_np_sent1 + 1;
    np_sent1[len_np_sent1] = np_sent2[x]
```

**To**

```py
np_sent1 = np.append(np_sent1, np_sent2)
```

**OR**

```py
np_sent1 = np.concatenate((np_sent1, np_sent2))
```